# I just want the IDs?

Tags: apex, soql

I want to get the IDs for all tasks...

I try:

```
List<String> ids = [SELECT ID FROM Task];
```

But that's give an illegal assignment error.  I can't just assign from Tasks to Strings. So what is the short hand way to write this?

Thanks

Answer (score 16, accepted):

This won't work, because the SOQL query will return a `List<Task>` regardless of the fields you query, however if you only need the ids, best thing you can do is make a map, then read the keyset, to get a set of Ids;

```
Map<Id, Task> taskMap = new Map<Id, Task>([SELECT Id FROM Task]);
```

now you have a set with ids you can use by doing:

```
Set<Id> taskIds = taskMap.keySet();
```

Comment: PJC's answer is correct.
If you want a quick modification to your code; just use this: List<Task> ids = [SELECT ID FROM Task]; then you can iterate over them using: for(Task t: ids){ System.debug(t); }

Answer (score 0):

To get a list of strings you're going to have to loop over the results. Not super efficient but if you're not doing a whole lot else (seemingly the case since you only want one field) then you should be ok on limits:

```
List<String> ids = new List<String>();

for(Task t : [select Id from Task])
  ids.add(t.Id);
```

I suspect you might be just getting these to use in a sebsequent query, so you should be aware than you can do a subquery:

```
... where Task__c in (select Id from Task)
```

Comment: That's a huge waste of script statements (performance + spam in the debug log), shortcut via map is better;) And regarding the last bit - usually yes but for whatever reason Tasks & Events can't be used like that. `SELECT Id FROM Account WHERE Id IN (SELECT AccountId FROM Task)` will not even compile.

Comment: Oh absolutely, hence I called it out and voted for the other answer myself ;)