# What is the best way to add to an apex collection of String

Tags: apex, soql, sobject, collection

Is there a more efficient way to `Select` data into a **`String`** collection e.g. `Set<String>` than using a for loop

```
Set<String> allTopicSet = new Set<String>();    
for (Topic t: [select name from Topic]) {
    allTopicSet.add(t.Name);
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There isn't, you can only get the Id of a list of objects easily by converting the list to a map and getting the keyset. (See [I just want the IDs?](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/9331/i-just-want-the-ids/9332#9332))

I'm afraid you're stuck to looping over the list, and adding them manually like you are doing now.